# SSAS Column Calculation Best Practice

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

My goal is to break down by customer and date the % of pass by subject.

So my dimensions are:
DimCustomer: CustomerID, CustomerName, State
DimSubject: SubjectID, Subject, Category
DimDate: DateKey, Year, Quarter, Month
FactTestResults: TestID, CustomerID, SubjectID, DateKey, Result (pass or fail)

Does it make more sense to calculate my pass % in the datawarehouse, SSAS or SSRS? If SSAS or SSRS, how do I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your cube breakdown, it looks like the result as a "pass / fail" value rather than a value.  You will have to hold pass % or more generically useful the score and subject max score (e.g. 59 / 70) so that you can work out the pass percentage.  If you keep the actual score, you can work out percentage pass across all subjects or percentage for all customers within a subject.

I would add a calculated measure to SSAS to work out the percentage, keeping all the logic within the cube.  This has the benefit of keeping all the logic within the cube, allowing you to consume percentage from all client tools (e.g. Excel, SSMS).  This also has the benefit of transferring less data around as only the final % value will go down to the SSRS server, not both the actual and subject max score.